# Angular ngCordova Datepicker doesnt display

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, ngcordova

I installed ngCordova datepicker and I can't find why the datepicker isnt working :

**1) My view where I integrated the ng-click="datepicker()":**

```
<a ng-click="datepicker()" class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" href="#">
  <img id= "icon_calendar" src="../img/icon_calendrier.svg"/>
  <p class="time_date"> </p>
  <img class= "flechedate" src="../img/fleche_bleuclaire.svg"/>
</a>
```

**2) My controller (following the doc in ngCordova website):**

```
angular.module('foot',[]).controller('FootController', function ($scope, $cordovaDatePicker) {
 $scope.foot;
 $scope.datepicker = function(){
  var options = {
    date: new Date(),
    mode: 'date', // or 'time'
    minDate: new Date() - 10000,
    allowOldDates: false,
    allowFutureDates: true,
    doneButtonLabel: 'DONE',
    doneButtonColor: '#F2F3F4',
    cancelButtonLabel: 'CANCEL',
    cancelButtonColor: '#000000'
  };
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

    $cordovaDatePicker.show(options).then(function(date){
        alert(date);


    });

  }, false);
};

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to include ngCordova as a dependency in your angular module.

```
angular.module('foot', ['ngCordova'])
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the type of "new Date() - 10000" is not Date, but Number. You can refer to the link http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ngcordova-datepicker-show-twice/16158.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this it is worked for me
You have to write the datePicker functionality in $ionicPlatform as

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
      $cordovaDatePicker.show(options).then(function(date){
        alert(date);
      });
```

I am uploading a sample project for you in git hub this is the [link](https://github.com/anilkumar007/DatePicker)
Having any queries, please reply  back